# Attempting to replace two character string with /dev/random hex

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tr

Example string

```
CA DA 00 17 11 38 88 C5 03
```

Desired output

```
 AB 3C 6C 8F DA 88 24 78 6C
```

Commands attempted

```
 $ tr -dc 0-9A-F < /dev/urandom filename  ## prints too many chars

awk '{gsub(length($1)==2,{printf "%02")}}' filename  ## syntax doesn't work, unsure how to add hex

 $ sed 's/[a-z0-9]\{2\}//g' filename  ## only replaces digits, unsure how to add hex as a replacement
```

I ended up using vim to do a partial conversion for some level of randomization.

```
 :s/\d\d/AA/g
```

Can anyone provide a working solution?

It would be nice to see solutions (and explanations) leveraging tr/awk/sed for knowledge sharing purposes.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't quite picture what you need as a result. Do you really need to show 100+ wide sample data? why not < 20? and edit your Q to show how you would like that modified. I'm thinking it will be a lot easier to do if you convert your data to 1 pair per line, randomize it, and then restore to a left-to-right string. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter, I would like to convert each existing pair to a randomized pair of hex values. I can convert it to 1 pair per line (i.e. tr ' ' '\n') but am not sure how to randomize it. i.e. 1F -> 8D

Comment: So did you really just want to generate a new string of X length with random hex values? Did the old data have anything to do with the problem, except the count of chars? Looks like good solutions below. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace each field with a random 2-digit hex number with awk is just:

```
$ awk -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=sprintf("%02X",rand()*256)} 1' file
C7 A1 02 1A 4A 94 95 A0 1E

$ awk -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=sprintf("%02X",rand()*256)} 1' file
1C 50 A9 D3 8B B0 24 9C 14
```

Hopefully it's very obvious what it's doing.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for the answer. At the beginning I can see that you have initialized $RANDOM. Can you explain why srand(seed) is needed? As well as rand()*256? I would assume that $RANDOM can be used for the awk expression.

Comment: $RANDOM is a shell construct. The script is awk. Awk is not shell. Therefore no, $RANDOM can't be used for the awk expression. Having said that I'm using srand() so we get a different output for every execution of awk and I'm using the value of $RANDOM as an initial seed for srand() so it starts with a different seed even if the script is called twice in 1 second (the default seed is the current time). See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Numeric-Functions.

Comment: The range of 2-digit hex numbers is 00 to FF which is 0 to 255 decimal. rand() outputs a fraction that's 0 <= output < 1. So to get a random integer between 0 and 255 you do int(rand()*256). In this case the sprint("%X") is doing the "int()" part so no need to do it explicitly. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140756/133219 for the general case of generating a random number in a range.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea on how to get a random hex (mac address?)

```
awk -v seed=$RANDOM '
    BEGIN{
        srand(seed);
        split("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F",hex," ");
        for (i=1; i<=6; i++) 
            printf "%s%s ",hex[int(rand()*16)+1],hex[int(rand()*16)+1];
        print ""
    }'
D8 D9 BA 00 6A C6
```